# Bind value to label in MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Am not able to bind values to label which i have declared it as

```
 @Html.Label("lblFname", "") in MVC4.
```

I believe that lblFname will acts as an id. 
so in document.ready function am just binding the value but its not happening

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lblFname').html("ABC123");
  })
```

even i tried with  $('#lblFname').text("ABC123") this also did not work. 
Even i ajax call i tried to bind the value

```
 $("#LocationName").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("FillSiteDropdown")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { LocID: $("#LocationName").val() },
                    success: function (Siteitems) {

                        $("#SiteName").data = null;
                        $("#SiteName").empty();
                        $.each(Siteitems, function (i, st) {

                              $('#lblFname').html("ABC123");
                        });
                    }
                });
            })
```

Successfully i can make ajax cal, but am not able to bind the text value. Please advice how to bind the text value to label. Thanks

Comment: `@Html.Label("lblFname", "")` does not generate an `id` attribute in the `<label>` element - inspect the html you generate - it generates a `for` attribute which in your case is pointless unless you also have a control named `lblFname` which I assume (and hope) you do not. But why are you using javascript instead of just `@Html.Label("lblFname", "ABC123")` or just `<span>ABC123</span>` since you not really creating a label

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
@Html.Label("lblFname", "")
```

The first parameter is an expression that identifies the property to display, as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453858(v=vs.108).aspx).

As you are not really using it for model binding, why using the helper at all and instead just do this:

```
<label id="lblFname" />
```

Comment: if i declare it as normal label then how would i get the value in my action, as am creating the object of the view class. Here it is

Comment: public ActionResult EditMasterData(MasterManagement mmtObj)

Comment: MasterManagement is my class too

Comment: That's a completely different question. If you want to ask that, you should post another question.

Comment: i generally access the property value like mmtobj.txtFirstname mmtobj.txtAddress etc.. so that can use those values for my further calculations.